# Cant get Facebook like button to include certain image

Tags: facebook-like

I cant seem to get the Facebook like button to include my image, checked the facebook dev docs and implemented what they say but i must be doing something wrong cause its picking a completely different image.

Here is my code:

in

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://url.com/images/81341089.jpg" />
```

And the button..

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=313222255403082";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://url.com/index.php" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Getting super frustrated :))

Comment: Check the debug tool here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - also check you meet the image size requirements or it won't display your image even if the tag is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;
window.open(‘http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=’+encodeURIComponent(u)+
’&t=’+encodeURIComponent(t),’sharer’,'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436′);
return false;}</script>
<a href=”http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>” onclick=”return fbs_click()” target=”_blank”>
<img src=”**ADD_IMAGE_URL_HERE**” alt=”Share on Facebook” />
</a>
```

I found it here http://www.business.com/b2bmarketing/create-share-buttons/